# Circle rotation (dynamic system)

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Here's a passage of my script I do not understand.

> > Define $\Omega:=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}: \lvert z\rvert =1\right\}$ and consider $a\in [0,1)$. Then
> >     $$
> > T_a:=\Omega\to\Omega, z\mapsto z\cdot \exp(2\pi ia)
> > $$
> >     defines a dynamical system.

Now my questions are:

(1) What exactly does $T_a$ do? If I have f.e. $a=0$ then $T_a(z)=z$.

(2) Why does $T_a$ define a dynamical system (definition below)? What is here $(X,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$?

---

Our definition of dynamical system:

> > A quadrupel $(X,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P},T)$ is called a dynamic system if $(X,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ is a probability space and $T\colon X\to X$ is a measurable transformation that holds the measure, i.e. $\mathbb{P}\circ T^{-1}=\mathbb{P}$.

Comment: $\exp(2\pi ia)$ just rotates around the center by $2\pi a$ radians.

Comment: I don't know the answer to part $2$ but $T_a$ will rotate a complex number in $\Omega$ around the origin. $a$ stands for the number of revolutions.

Comment: $X=\Omega$, $\mathcal A$ the Borel sigma-algebra on $\Omega$, $P$ proportional to the Lebesgue measure on the circle, assigning measure $(\arg(v)-\arg(u))/(2\pi)$ to each arc $\widehat{(u,v)}$, $T=T_a$.